# PassportJS Custom Authenticate Callback Not Called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

**Update: The below error was fixed by [a commit](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/186). I've marked the first answer as 'correct', though the commit was brought to my attention in one of its comments**

I was hoping to utilize the custom callback to handle both successes and failures for logins in Passport's [authenticate local strategy](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), but it looks like it's only called on success.

Here is a snippet of what I'm talking about:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'},
    function(email, password, done) {
        if(canLogin) done(null, user);
        else done({message: "This is an error message" }, false, { message: "Some Info" });
    }
));


app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
         // Only called if err is not set
    });
```

Any idea why this might be the case? I was under the impression the callback would be called so I can handle errors myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to propagate an authentication failure (username/password mismatch), you shouldn't generate an error, but set the `user` to `false` and pass a reason along:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  {usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'},
  function(email, password, done) {
    if (canLogin)
      done(null, user);
    else 
      done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid login credentials' });
  }
));
...
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (user === false) {
      // handle login error ...
    } else {
      // handle successful login ...
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The `err` is reserved for exceptions that occur during the authentication process, for instance if you get DB-errors and such. But although the Passport docs suggest that those errors will be passed to the `passport.authenticate` callback, they don't seem to (which is the reason why it's not working for you).

Comment: Yep, was just using those as examples. So I guess there's no workaround to this then?

Comment: @funseiki looking at the Passport code, 'proper' errors are passed along the middleware chain, not to the callback. You can't do anything about that I'm afraid, apart from setting up a global Express error handler that will handle these errors.

Comment: If a custom callback is supplied, errors are now propagated to it.  See here for more info: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/186

Comment: @robertklep I am getting err,user,info as null,false,missing credentials in passport.authencate. I didnt set user to false. can you please look into my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898027/passport-js-local-strategy-custom-callback-showing-user-as-false-and-info-as-mi