# req (request) is not defined for passportjs.use in SailsJS

Tags: express, request, response, sails.js, passport.js

I want to use req.flash("message" : error ) to support error message callbacks for passportJS inside of SailsJS. However, PassportJS does not handle the below during callbacks: (similar post: [PassportJS Custom Authenticate Callback Not Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206583/passportjs-custom-authenticate-callback-not-called))

```
//there is no req found
req.flash("message" , "invalid password");
```

This usually will be alright if there's something like:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
  //....
  req.flash("message" , "invalid password");
}
```

But I can't use it inside passport.use.

```
/services/passport.js
passport.use(new HttpBasicStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      // Find the user by username.  If there is no user with the given
      // username, or the password is not correct, set the user to `false` to
      // indicate failure.  Otherwise, return the authenticated `user`.
      findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
          return done(null, err);
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Unknown user ' + username
          });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
          if (!res){

       -->  //there is no req found
       -->  req.flash("message" , "invalid password");

            return done(null, false, {
              message: 'Invalid Password'
            });
          }
          var returnUser = {
            username: user.username,
            createdAt: user.createdAt,
            id: user.id
          };
          return done(null, returnUser, {
            message: 'Logged In Successfully'
          });
        });
      })
    });
  }
));
```

Is there another way to call req.flash? I'm pretty new at express and sailsjs, please pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

For sails v0.10.x [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) is perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I have tried that already but it doesn't have what I needed. (Passport-http).

Comment: Actually, it also supports passport-http... I'm using this  https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer EDIT: Don't know if passport-http is similar to passport-http-bearer...

Comment: It doesn't, I have suggested the author to make one. But until then I can't really use it. And I'm using quite a customised version of passport which requires updating on callback. And I might as well customise passport myself. (:

Comment: You can tweak services/passport.js of sails-generate-auth.. I can see `req` param there...