# Passport js local strategy custom callback showing user as false and info as “Missing credentials”

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using Node.js,angularjs,express and passport. I have tried all options I can think of, but still no solution. Couldn't find a solution from other posts for this problem.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

console.log(req.body.Email);
console.log(req.body.Password);

passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

    console.log(err,user,info);
...
```

In above req.body is showing correct in console  but in passport authenticate it is showing null,false and info as missing credentials.

I have used the following for pass port

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'Email' }, (Email, Password, done) => {
console.log(Email, Password, done);
User.findOne({ Email: Email.toLowerCase() }, (err, user) => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { msg: `Email ${Email} not found.` });
    }
    user.ComparePassword(Password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
        }
        return done(null, false, { msg: 'Invalid email or password.' });
    });
});
}));


passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
   // console.log(user, done);
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

I couldn't understand why the problem exist.

Does anybody know what I am missing here?!?!

Thanks!

Comment: can you try passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy ...continue normally,  and then call it by passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user, info)... does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding upto kaxi answer I have made to solve this error by adding password field in the passport local strategy as below

```
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'Email',passwordField: 'Password'  }, (Email, Password, done)
```

in place of

`passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'Email' }, (Email, Password, done)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `{ usernameField: 'email' }` not `{ usernameField: 'Email' }` because you send `req.body.email` not `req.body.Email`

Comment: Also, the variable `Email` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @robertklep and kaxi sorry I am using req.body.Email mistakenly i menioned there wrong. I have edited the question

Comment: @charantej add `passwordField` field too, so it should look like this: 
`{ usernameField: 'Email' , passwordField: 'Password' }`

Comment: @kaxi1993 tried but of no use. I kept console.log inside local strategy but it is not printing. it is just printing the passport.autenticate only and as in question. user as false and missing credentials

Comment: Even i tried for calling callback passReqToCallback: true in that

Comment: @kaxi1993  It worked if I add only the PasswordField.